# Arrange the following functions in increasing order of growth rate

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

Arrange the following functions in increasing order of growth rate (with $g(n)$ following $f(n)$ in your list if and only if $f(n)=O(g(n))$.

a)$2^{\log⁡(n)}$

b)$2^{2^{log⁡(n)}}$

c)$n^{5/2}$

d)$2^{n^2}$

e)$n^2\log(n)$

**My attempt**
Suppose logarithm here is base 2, we can write

$(a)2^{\log⁡(n)}=n$

$(b)2^{2^{log⁡(n)}}=2^n$
comparing (a),(b), (c) and (d) we have (a)<<(c)<<(b)<<(d).

Consider (a) and (e)

$\frac{n}{n^2\log_2(n)}=\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. So (a)<<(e)

Therefore Order of growth is (a)<<(e)<<(c)<<(b)<<(d).

But In examination, It is shown that my order is wrong. Where is my mistake? Was my thinking wrong?

Comment: For logarithm with base $2$ your order is correct.

Comment: Adding onto what zkutch said, you'll want to use change of base formula to convert the logarithms to base $2$ from base $10$ (assuming that they are common logs and not natural logs).